# Null pointer when I try to findViewById and call setAlpha

Tags: android, android-layout, findviewbyid

My Activity:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

activity_main.xml:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:background="@drawable/sk_collection_bg_default"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:height="35dp"
        android:elevation="4dp">
```

The crash:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setAlpha(0);
    }
```

Null pointer exception when attempting to set Alpha.

Why is the view null?

Comment: you must reference your views inside the `onCreate()` method of activity.

Comment: Why? I can reference views in any function.

Comment: because layout is initialised inside the `onCreate` method by `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` and you can reference your view at initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration should be set on Create not on Resume.

Comment: Declaration? The same code crashes there if I try that.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing looks wrong in your code.

May be you are importing `android.widget.Toolbar` rather than `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;`

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
onCreate(Bundle) is where you initialize your activity. Most importantly, here you will usually call **setContentView(int)** with a layout resource defining your UI, and using **findViewById(int)** to retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with programmatically.

Comment: you can findViewbyId in any function inside of an Activity. It crashes regardless if it's in onCreate or onResume.